# Get DateTime knowing Date

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.5

How do I query DateTime database field? I have PHP variable **$date** (format YYYY-MM-DD). **date** in my database have YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format. I am using MySQL 5.5.

Error code below:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `date`LIKE $date
```

Note that I need to get rows with format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Comment: What is the datatype of this date field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LIKE like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `date` LIKE '$date %'
```

or the better solution:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `date` BETWEEN
  '$date 00:00:00' AND '$date 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Something is not quite right. I don't know date value. The user has to enter the data, and I will keep them in a variable $date (YYYY-MM-DD)

Comment: @Geronimo You may have posted that before my edit. I adjusted it to use the `$date` variable.

Comment: @Geronimo You're welcome. A note - if you're using it as-shown, you **must** validate the date field to ensure the user didn't put in bad data. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left` function:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE left(`date`,10) = $date
```

That will get the first 10 characters from your date field and will match the value in your variable.

Comment: That'll run `LEFT()` on every single row in the database, disregarding indexes, and is as a result very inefficient.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but it looks like I'm comparing HH:MM:SS and YYYY-MM-DD. Or not?